# Closed form of this product or approximate?

Tags: calculus, arithmetic, products, infinite-product, approximation-theory

What is the closed form of this product:

$$\prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(1-e^{-a(b- ic)^2}\right)$$

where $a,b,c$ are constants?

Comment: Better to include the whole question here, than to make people go offsite to find it.

Comment: Hi, could you tell us what you've tried?

Comment: I  calculate probability of success for a system. for each stage probability of success equals  $$ e^{-a(b- k*c)^2} * \prod_{i=1}^{k-1}\left(1-e^{-a(b- ic)^2}\right)$$.  So I want to find closed form. I can simplify to $$ \prod_{i=w}^{n}\left(1-e^{-i}\right)$$

Comment: How do you get rid of the $i^2$?

Comment: By changing the limit of product

Comment: This product was studied by Hardy and Ramanujan.